# Bootstrap change div order with pull-right, pull-left on 3 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

I’ve been working on this the whole day but don’t come up with a solution. I have 3 columns in one row in a container.

1: right content – pull-right

2: navigation – pull-left

3: main content

What it looks on big screens:

```
------------------------------------------------
|   Menu  |      Content      |  Right Content |
------------------------------------------------
```

What it should look like on smaller screens:

```
----------------------------
|  Menu  |  Right Content  |
|        |------------------
|        |  Content        |
----------------------------
```

What it looks like now:

```
------------------
| Right Content  |
------------------
| Menu | Content |
------------------
```

I think it’s just a simple floating problem. But I tried out nearly all possibilities.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

### Bootstrap 3

Using Bootstrap 3's grid system:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Menu</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">Right Content</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://bootply.com/93614

#### Explanation

First, we set two columns that will stay in place no matter the screen resolution (`col-xs-*`).

Next, we divide the larger, right hand column in to two columns that will collapse on top of each other on tablet sized devices and lower (`col-md-*`).

Finally, we shift the display order using the matching class (`col-md-[push|pull]-*`). You push the first column over by the amount of the second, and pull the second by the amount of the first.

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
          Right content
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">
          Content
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/93612)

Comment: Having both `col-sm-X` and `col-md-X` is unnecessary. If you set the grid at sm, it will stay in place at md.

Comment: Also, you should always wrap columns in a `row` so it will trim the gutters off the first and last columns. See http://bootply.com/93628 for a visual explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but for the latest BS 5 this can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#offsetting-columns using offset classes.