# How do i move my left element below my middle element on smaller screen (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to move my `left element(bild)` below my `middle element(col-md-4)`,when I shrink the screen. As it is now my picture ends up above my text.

> How can i make my left (bild) element end up below my middle element(col-md-4) on small screens?

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="headerfilo"></div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="headfil">
            <div class="col-md-5" style="background-color: #FF9999">Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>FILOSOFI</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: #FF9999">Right</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="midfil">
            <div class="col-md-5"> 
                <div id="bild" class="bildfilo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <p>Trivs du med att arbeta agilt, med prestigelöshet och i en platt organisation där dina prestationer syns och uppmärksammas? Då kan  vara företaget för dig. Just nu har vi öppningar på följande positioner men vi är alltid intresserade av nya talanger </p>

                <p>Trivs du med att arbeta agilt, med prestigelöshet och i en platt organisation där dina prestationer syns och uppmärksammas? Då kan vara företaget för dig. Just nu har vi öppningar på följande positioner men vi är alltid intresserade av nya talanger</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:#FF9999">Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions need question marks "?" It is otherwise unclear what you are asking.

Comment: sorry i hope its clearer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pull left` or `pull-right` classes for the div you want to relocate.

For more info-

Please refer [Bootstrap: change div order with pull-right, pull-left / 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929213/bootstrap-change-div-order-with-pull-right-pull-left-3-columns)

Comment: Thank you, found out that i just had to order my elements around to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this through 2 simple ways (there are even more, but those are the most easiest which currently came into my mind).

**1. You could use Bootstraps build in functionalities**

Bootstrap provides you some classes, which affect your markup regarding to your current screen width. That being said, you could 2 containers (1 before and 1 after your main part) which appear to be visible depending on your screen width. In order to do so, you may use `.visible-xs-*` and `.hidden-xs`. To learn more, take a look at [this](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

**2. Use your own media rules**

Another approach would be to use your own responsive media rules. So this basically means the same as using Bootstraps build in functionality, just without using multiple containers. A simple solution would look like this:

```
@media (max-width: 760px)  {
  .top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
  .left {
    margin-top: 5em;
  }
}
```

You can check it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tX3ae/655/) as well.