# Responsive Layout : How to switch positions in smartphone layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I how can I solve this responsive layout case:
I have three boxes.
On wide screens I want two of them on the left with a fixed width and the other one on the right.
On small screens I want all boxes to become 100% and the right one to be between the other two.

I´ve made a fiddle that almost works, but I need to get rid of that gap in wide mode.

https://jsfiddle.net/ypmgo7no/3/

```
.leftfixed {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  background:purple;
  height:50px;
}

.right {
  margin-left:220px;
  background:yellow;
  height:100px;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .leftfixed {
    float:none;
      width:100%;
      background:blue;
   }

   .right {
     margin-left:0;
     }
}
```

See the problem: (sorry, just realised that "Wide mode" and "Small mode" in the image are interchanged)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pxMr.png)

Comment: media queries are not the problem. Please read the Question. Thanks

Comment: I can't see the gap between those in the fiddle?

Comment: @SatejS: Sorry, I updated the fiddle, the boxes need to have height: https://jsfiddle.net/ypmgo7no/3/

Comment: if you are talking about gap between two purple div then its because of height of right yellow div..

Comment: It might be help you check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929213/bootstrap-change-div-order-with-pull-right-pull-left-3-columns

Comment: That's primarily happening because the your right hand side div is placed before the third div, and this that much space is occupied.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/ypmgo7no/4/

Comment: You want something like this is what I'm guessing https://jsfiddle.net/wx5ck69s/ It isn't responsive in a smaller mode in this case

Comment: The solution by @Leothelion is spot on.

Comment: ok posting as answer..hope you will accept.. :)

Comment: @Leothelion  But thats the point, that the right div has a specific height... so your fiddle doesnt help: https://jsfiddle.net/ypmgo7no/8/

Comment: @Flasher, check back my updated fiddle in my answer.

Comment: @BalvantAhir: Looks interesting, but I don´t know if and how this can be adepted to fit to this case

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```css
.leftfixed {
  float:none;
  width:200px;
  background:purple;
  height:100px;
}

.right {
    left: 220px;
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 7px;
  }

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .leftfixed {
    float:none;
      width:100%;
      background:blue;
   }
   
   .right {
     margin-left:0;
     position:inherit;
     
     }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftfixed">
box left fixed width 1
</div>

<div class="right">
box right
</div>

<div class="leftfixed">
box left fixed width 2
</div>
```

Comment: Ok that works, but I thought there could be a solution without position:absolute :-/

Comment: okay. No problem. I will try without trying position:absolute. wait for minute.

Comment: you don't want to use position property anywhere??

Comment: ideally not :) But I don´t know it it´s possible

Comment: because position property have to use. i made updated still there is position property is used

Answer (score 0):

This is another method i added class **bottom** to last div and added **position:relative** and **bottom:100px** in your original code.

```css
.leftfixed {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  background:purple;
  height:100px;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 220px;
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    top: 7px;
  }
  .bottom{
       position: relative;
     bottom: 100px;
  }

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .leftfixed {
    float:none;
      width:100%;
      background:blue;
   }
   
   .right {
     margin-left:0;
   
     
     }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftfixed">
box left fixed width 1
</div>

<div class="right">
box right
</div>

<div class="leftfixed bottom">
box left fixed width 2
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of posting two answer, you should updated your last one or add this in last answer..

Comment: ya. Actually i added 2nd answer separately because @flasher will understand.

Comment: please tell me. My answers are proper or not?