# buttons aligment in bootstrap model footer

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nltGE.png)I am adding buttons in model-footer but it is not getting aligned in line instead it comes to next line.

```
<div class="modal-footer">              
         <form method="post" action="admin_view">
           <a type="submit" name="accepted" value="<?php echo $object['id'];?>" class="btn btn-success">Accepted Job</a> 
          </form>

          <form method="post" action="reject_job">
             <a type="submit" name="rejected" value="<?php echo $object['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Rejected Job</a> 
          </form>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: you dont have them in one line because form have a display:block;

Answer (score 0):

Use "pull-left" class in btn.  Or if you want to right then use "pull-right"
Do you want more help. go to this url for reference [Bootstrap: change div order with pull-right, pull-left / 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929213/bootstrap-change-div-order-with-pull-right-pull-left-3-columns)

```
<div class="modal-footer">              
         <form method="post" action="admin_view">
           <a type="submit" name="accepted" value="<?php echo $object['id'];?>" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Accepted Job</a> 
          </form>

          <form method="post" action="reject_job">
             <a type="submit" name="rejected" value="<?php echo $object['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger pull-left">Rejected Job</a> 
          </form>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="modal-footer">  

   <div class="col-md-4">
       <form method="post" action="admin_view">
           <a type="submit" name="accepted" value="<?php echo $object['id'];?>" class="btn btn-success">Accepted Job</a> 
      </form>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
      <form method="post" action="reject_job">
           <a type="submit" name="rejected" value="<?php echo $object['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Rejected Job</a> 
      </form>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
   </div>

</div>
```